# How to add a mathematical operation to a List<>?

Tags: c#

I'm sorry most of the program is in Spanish since that's my main language and it's a bit of a mess but it's short.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Tarea_2
{
    class Demo
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Write("¿Cuántos números desea entrar? ");
              int cun = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Entre "+cun+" números");
            Console.WriteLine("Oprima 'Enter' después de cada uno.");
            //unaLista recoge los valores directamente del usuario
              List<int> unaLista = new List<int>();
              for (int i = 0; i < cun; i++)
                  unaLista.Add(Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("¿Qué cantidad desea sumar a cada número? ");
              int sum = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();
            //otraLista los copia de unaLista y les suma la variable "sum"
              **List<int> otraLista = new List<int>();
                          otraLista.AddRange(unaLista);**

            Mostrar(unaLista);
            Mostrar(otraLista);
        }//End of Main

        public static void Mostrar(List<int> a)
        {
            foreach (int valor in a)
                Console.WriteLine(valor);
                Console.WriteLine();
        }//End of Mostrar
    }//End of Demo
}//End of namespace
```

Anyway, I'm saving a variable that comes from the user on "sum" that I need to SUM to the total of each number that was copied to "otraLista" through AddRange from "unaLista". Is this possible?

edit: I always do these kind of things with arrays but this was my first time using Lists (since is supposed to be better), so many many thanks, this worked really nice:

**List otraLista = unaLista.Select(i => i + sum).ToList();**

Expected Results below:

¿Cuántos números desea entrar? **3**

Entre 3 números.
Oprima 'Enter' después de cada uno.

**20**

**30**

**40**

¿Qué cantidad desea sumar a cada número? **100**

20

30

40

120

130

140

Press 'Enter' to finish...

Comment: Could you edit your question and add an example, where say `cun` is 2 or 3, and the other inputs and expected result?

Comment: I added the entire code, plus, the "Expected Results" at the end.

Comment: I wasn't sure, but Kendall's second answer seems to give the expected result.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with LINQ:

```
otraLista = otraLista.Select(i => i + sum).ToList();
```

Or if you want to do it before the AddRange, you can skip the `new List<int>` and `AddRange` and do this instead:

```
List<int> otraLista = unaLista.Select(i => i + sum).ToList();
```

Make sure you are

```
using System.Linq;
```